# C++ Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when using xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, std, mutex

I have the following piece of code:

```
// Critical section, lock mutex
m_dbMutex.lock();
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int ret = sqlite3_prepare(m_dbConnection, query, -1, &statement, 0);
if(ret == SQLITE_OK)
{
    ret = sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
m_dbMutex.unlock();
// End of critical section
```

Where `m_dbMutex`is a std::mutex object, which is declared in the header in the following way:

```
static std::mutex m_dbMutex;
```

For some reason, i can't compile my program because of this.
Full error print:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "DBManager::m_dbMutex", referenced from:
      DBManager::runQuery(char const*) in DBManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried adding `libc++.tbd` and `libstdc++.tbd` to my project but it still won't compile.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

It seems this happens when the mutex is declared static. 
I don't get this error when it's not.

Comment: Did you provide a definition also?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand what you were referring to, definition of what?

Comment: For the `static std::mutex m_dbMutex;` of course. You'll need a definition like `std::mutex DBManager::m_dbMutex;` in your source file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Damn! forgot about it. thanks a lot, it solved it!